# How to remove or merge misspelled row in python? Using pandas or other lib

Tags: python, pandas

I have 5 rows where the class name is different(typo) but contains the same data.
Such as

```
> classs                                 ...                      
> Iris-setosa                   44       ...                    44
> Iris-setossa                   1       ...                     1
> Iris-versicolor               45       ...                    45
> Iris-virginica                50       ...                    50
> versicolor                     5       ...                     5
```

Here I want to class Versicolor to merge with iris-Versicolor and iris-setossa(extra s) with iris-setosa.

I tried .join .concat function those are merging whole column with the row. as outer join, InnerJoin. But I want to treat the versicolor as a iris-versicolor and iris-setossa as iris-setosa.

Comment: Probably instead preprocess your input to normalize the labels before doing any processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [pandas-dedupe](https://github.com/Lyonk71/pandas-dedupe) library to remove typos in you dataset.
Example code

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_dedupe

df = pd.DataFrame({'class': ['Iris-setosa', 'Iris-setossa', 'Iris-versicolor', 'Iris-virginica', 'versicolor', 'iris-setosa', 'versicolor']})

dd = pandas_dedupe.dedupe_dataframe(
    df, 
    field_properties = ['class'], 
    sample_size=1,
    canonicalize=True
    )

# At this point pandas dedupe will ask you to label some records as distinct or duplicates.   
# Once done, you hit finish ('f') and here is the output:

#   class      cluster id   confidence  canonical_class
# 0 iris-setosa     0      1.000000       iris-setosa
# 1 iris-setossa    0      1.000000       iris-setosa
# 2 iris-versicolor 1      0.998748       versicolor
# 3 iris-virginica  2      1.000000       iris-virginica
# 4 versicolor      1      0.999115       versicolor
# 5 iris-setosa     0      1.000000       iris-setosa
# 6 versicolor      1      0.999115       versicolor
```

In case you have a clean list of names (i.e. gazette), you can also attempt to perform gazetteer deduplication whereby you remove duplicates by matching messy data against a gazette. pandas-dedupe supports gazetteer deduplication too.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have many rows with misspellings and it won't be a tedious task, you can just do it manually using `str.replace`:

```
df['class'] = df['class'].str.replace('Iris-setosa','Iris-setossa')
df['class'] = df['class'].str.replace('Iris-versicolor','versicolor')
```

Comment: Thanks, sophods but actually I have 5000 data and 10% of the data are misspelled.